# KubernetesPodOperator privileged security_context in Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running Airflow on Google's Cloud Composer. I am using the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator) and would like to mount a google storage bucket to a directory in pod via [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse). It seems like to do this I need to give k8s privileged security context as specified [here](https://github.com/maciekrb/gcs-fuse-sample). It seems like airflow recently added the security_context parameter to the KubernetesPodOperator. The security context I am specifying in the operator is :

```
security_context = {
  'securityContext': {
    'privileged': True,
    'capabilities':
      {'add': ['SYS_ADMIN']}
  }
}
```

When I try running `airflow test dag_id task_id date` in the airflow worker, the pod launches and when the code tries to mount the bucket via gcsfuse it throws the error `"fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first"`. This makes it seems as the security_context is not working ([ex.](https://serverfault.com/questions/924793/gcsfuse-in-google-app-engine-flexible-custom-runtime)).

Am I misunderstanding what the security_context parameter in the operator and/or is my securityContext dictionary definition invalid?

Comment: Which image version for Cloud Composer are you using?

Comment: composer-1.8.1-airflow-1.10.3

Comment: In the source code, it seems like in v1.10.3 security_context is in the airflow source code, but undocumented?

Comment: If you have a pod left over from one of the DAG runs, could you dump its yaml?

Comment: That's a good point.
It seems like securityContext is {}, so it seems like Airflow just isn't passing on the security context to the pod

Comment: @hexacyanide is right in his answer below, the security context you're trying to pass is a context for pod not for container, to define security context for the container you should use pod definition through the `kubernetes.client.models.V1Pod`

Answer (score 5):

The `security_context` kwarg for the KubernetesPodOperator sets the security context for the pod, not a specific container within the pod, so it only supports the options outlined in [`PodSecurityContext`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core). Since the parameters you are specifying aren't valid for a pod's security context, they are being discarded.

The `privileged` and `capabilities` properties are only valid as part of a container's [`SecurityContext`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#securitycontext-v1-core), meaning you'll need to somehow set them on the pod's ***container*** spec. You can do this by defining the entire pod spec yourself (as opposed to having the operator generate it for you). Using KubernetesPodOperator, you can set `full_pod_spec` or `pod_template_file` to specify a Kubernetes API Python object, or path to an object YAML, which would then be used to generate the pod. Example using the former:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
import kubernetes.client.models as k8s

pod = k8s.V1Pod()
pod.spec = k8s.V1PodSpec()
pod.spec.containers = [
    k8s.V1Container(
      ...,
      security_context={
          'privileged': True,
          'capabilities': {'add': ['SYS_ADMIN']}
      }
    )
]

# Equivalent to setting security_context from the operator
pod.spec.security_context = {}

t1 = KubernetesPodOperator(..., full_pod_spec=pod)
```

If you want to use `pod_template_file` with Cloud Composer, you can upload a pod YAML to GCS and set it to one of the [mapped storage paths](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage) (e.g. `/home/airflow/gcs/dags/my-pod.yaml` if you put it in the DAGs directory.

Reading through the `airflow.providers.google.cloud` version of KubernetesPodOperator, it's possible that `full_pod_spec` is broken in newer version of the operator. However, it should work with the old contrib version.

Comment: I've surfed the code for Airflow 1.10.6 and also found out that `full_pod_spec` doesn't get processed there and container's security_context doesn't get set if you put it to `V1Pod` definition. But looks like in 1.10.12 (which is the latest in Cloud Composer at us-central1-b) they've fixed that and it's usable, but I didn't try it by myself. One more thing about the answer, Airflow throws empty containers error on such pod spec definition, you should pass a container list like this `k8s.V1PodSpec(containers[container])`.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue as well. The answer and comment above was so helpful. This is the code I resolved the issue.

```
    pod = k8s_models.V1Pod()
    containers = [
        k8s_models.V1Container(
            name='container_1',
            security_context={
                'privileged': True,
                'capabilities': {'add': ['SYS_ADMIN']}
            }
        )
    ]
    pod.spec = k8s_models.V1PodSpec(containers=containers)
```