# How to run docker image with --privileged in KubernetesPodOperator on airflow

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod, kubernetespodoperator

How do I `docker run` private image from Container Registry in GCP using `--privileged`
Running this locally works fine:

```
docker run -it --privileged --entrypoint /bin/bash ${GKE_APP}
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001647/kubernetespodoperator-privileged-security-context-in-airflow) but the error still persisted.

This is my DAG:

```
def process_backup_data(data_to_backup):

    secret_file = Secret('volume', '/etc/secrets', 'my-secret')

    task_env_vars = {'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS': "/etc/secrets/my-sa.json}
    

    security_context = {
                        'privileged': True,
                        'allow_privilege_escalation': True,
                        'capabilities': {'add': ['SYS_ADMIN']}
                       }

    return KubernetesPodOperator(image="asia.gcr.io/my-image:latest",
                         env_vars=task_env_vars,
                         cmds=["sh", "run-vpn-script.sh"],
                         arguments=[data_to_backup],
                         labels={"project": "my-project"},
                         name="my-project-backup-datasets",
                         task_id=f"backup_{task_id}",
                         dag=dag,
                         secrets=[secret_file],
                         image_pull_policy='Always',
                         security_context=security_context # HERE
                         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether you are missing some sort of capability?

I see in the example you posted they also add this to the `security_context`

```py
'capabilities': {'add': ['SYS_ADMIN']}
```

Comment: I added `capabilities` and still recurring

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting?

Comment: you need to add the capabilities to the security context of the specific container and not on the pod level!

Comment: @meaningqo how do I specify this?

Comment: @JorrickSleijster well, I check the produced yaml from GKE, it seems that the `securityContext` is empty. Where I expected it to have `privileged` value set to `True`. It seems that `KubernetesPodOperator` didn't catch the config I added..

Comment: I don't know how to do it with the pod operator unfortunately. 
all i can tell you is that the securityContext can be specified on pod level and on container level. capabilities are container specific and need to be defined on the containers security context.

Answer (score 0):

I think the security context is good direction. I believe you can customize every aspect of the Pod - including securityContext  by specifying pod_template_file

That requires - i think using Airflow 2 (which I heartily recommend) or using cncf.kubernetes backport provider. Note that the backport are already pretty old (we stopped releasing them 4 months ago) and the airflow 1.10 is end of life as of 17th of June so it won't receive even security fixes from the community, Airflow 2 route is more than recommended

Comment: I see, in this case my Airflow is'nt compatible as it is 1.10. Need to upgrade ASAP then. Thank you